# How to pass userdata to AWS Elastic beanstalk instance launched with custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need the elastic beanstalk instances which is launched with my custom AMI to run some userdata i.e: bash scripts.

I want to copy some files and execute my application .jar in user-data which is bundled in my custom AMI which has been created using packer.

Is there any way to do this with AWS elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Without knowing more of the particulars, I'd say a good place to start would be to look into .ebextensions since you're using beanstalk.   You can copy files, install applications, execute scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use .ebexentions you just need to write you bash script in a script_name.config YAML file and beanstalk will take care of it.
AWS Docs- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Reference hooks: https://github.com/equivalent/scrapbook2/blob/master/archive/blogs/2016-08-22-aws-elasticbeanstalk-hooks.md

Answer (score 0):

You can add configuration files to the .ebextensions directory.

For AWS Linux 2 platforms, look at Buildfile, Procfile and Platform hooks.

All these options are discussed here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html