# How to add user_data commands in elastic beanstalk created with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

With this script I create EB.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalkappenv" {
  name                = var.beanstalkappenv
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.elasticapp.name
  solution_stack_name = var.solution_stack_name
  tier                = var.tier

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = "${aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id}"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = "${aws_subnet.prod-subnet-public-1.id},${aws_subnet.prod-subnet-public-2.id}"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
    name      = "MatcherHTTPCode"
    value     = "200"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "InstanceType"
    value     = "t2.micro"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBScheme"
    value     = "internet facing"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = 1
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = 2
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name      = "SystemType"
    value     = "enhanced"
  }
  setting {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
      value     = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBAllocatedStorage"
    value     = "10"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBDeletionPolicy"
    value     = "Delete"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "HasCoupledDatabase"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngine"
    value     = "mysql"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngineVersion"
    value     = "8.0.28"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBInstanceClass"
    value     = "db.t3.micro"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBPassword"
    value     = "solvee-pos-unbreakable"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBUser"
    value     = "admin"
  }
}
```

At launch I need to initialize the RDS db so I need to cd into the app directory activate virtual environment, enter python shell and run db.create_all() coomand. Like this.

```
#! /bin/bash
cd ../var/app/current
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3
from application import db
db.create_all()
```

When creating an EC2 recource it would look like this

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-instance" {
    ami = "ami-04169656fea786776"
    instance_type = "t2.nano"
    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.terraform-demo.key_name}"
    user_data = "${file("initialize_db.sh")}"
    tags = {
        Name = "Terraform"  
        Batch = "5AM"
    }
```

}

but I'm creating the EC2 inside the EB I can't do it this way.
So how can I do it?
Sorry for spamming with tf questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514492/how-to-pass-userdata-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-instance-launched-with-custom-ami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EB you are not using `userdata`. Instead all your initialization code should be provided through [ebextentions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) or [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).